# Issues with VBA - Run-time error '6': Overflow

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I am stuck with this issue on VBA...
I need to create combinations but when N>22 and K=5, VBA is returning  Run-time error '6': Overflow.
I've tried to fix this by saving the file with .xlxs but the problem still remains.
So I've tried to switch the variables to 32-bit but I honestly don't know how to modify the code.

Please find it here below:

```
Public col(100), r, n, nr As Integer
Function comb(k)

col(k) = col(k - 1)
While col(k) < n - r + k

col(k) = col(k) + 1
If k < r Then
comb (k + 1)
Else
nr = nr + 1
For i = 1 To r
Cells(nr, i) = col(i)
Next
End If

Wend


End Function
```

Comment: `Public col(100), r, n, nr As double`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public col(100), r, n, nr As Integer
```

You must be assigning a higher value than an Integer can handle. Use Single, or for debugging reasons, declare them individually inside the function that way if the error persist it will highlight the variable with the error.

Do not use double as the output may require format, double = decimals, etc (as stated by enderland in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are becoming too big for the `int` or `long` to handle. for small numbers you can use the direct formula, and for larger numbers you can use either Stirling's approximation or Ramanujan's formula for factorial and store it in a `double`

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/09/25/ramanujans-factorial-approximation/